# need to res.json() to two separate endpoints, throws headers error (node/express)

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm having an issue sending the same json object to two separate endpoints. I need to send one copy to a database, and the other copy back to the client. I'm getting `can't set headers after they are sent`. Which I have gathered is an error saying that `res.json()` is called once, and can not be called a second time because the headers have been "baked in". I'm pretty newb to development, any suggestions or explanation would be very helpful.

Note: the whole code executes successfully, then crashes the server with the error message above.

```
paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log("Get Payment Response");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
                         const userData = {paymentID : payment.id};
            UserData.addUserData(userData, function(err, userData) {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              }
              res.json(userData);
            });
            res.json(userData)
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right when you write that you can't call `res.json()` a second time. You can only send one response per request. `res.json()` sends a response, so you can only call it once (you have probably seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7042340/8574934) question already).

You don't have to send a response to the database. Only the client that sent the request should receive a response. Calling `res.json()` will not send anything to the database. In order to store the `userData` object in the database, you have to call the function that does that. In your case, I assume you are doing that with `UserData.addUserData()`. This is where the storing happens, not by sending a response to it.

The function you send in as an argument to `UserData.addUserData()` is most likely a callback that is called AFTER storing the userData object is finished. Basically, `UserData.addUserData()` will do all the stuff it's supposed to do, and then continue with the function you have written after that. In there you can call `res.json()`. You can remove the last call to `res.json()`. It's not needed as you will call it in the callback function after storing in the database is finished.

```
paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log("Get Payment Response");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
            const userData = {paymentID : payment.id};
            UserData.addUserData(userData, function(err, userData) {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              }
              res.json(userData);
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This I'm seeing that I need to use db.open() as a way to establish connection to the database and send data. The tutorial that I followed to create the original code was utilizing a callback. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question :)